# how to keep receiving data from serialport

Tags: c#, dll

this is the class encapsulated in my dll

```
public class CommClass
    {
    public SerialPort _port;
    //

    public CommClass(string _pname)
    {
        portList = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        _port = new SerialPort(portList[0]);
        if (portList.Length < 1)
            _port= null;
        else
        {
            if(portList.Contains(_pname))
            { 
                _port = new SerialPort(_pname);
            //SerialPort _port = portList[0];
            //return _port; 
             }
        }
    }
```

i knew there is a SerialDataReceived ,how to encapsulate it into my dll?

Comment: Is the port initialized with InitializeComPort()?

Comment: @nullforce, no, its name is "com2",and i can send data ,just wrong with reading

Comment: i just add a line separator,then i works.